# Dumping JSON to file in a multithreaded environment

Tags: python, json, multithreading

I am using the following code within a multithreading environment:

```
with open("UrlDict.json",'a') as f:
     json.dump([text,href],f)
     f.write('\n')
```

but as one thread is adding to my desired file, another thread executes the f.write('\n') method and it messes things up. Is there a way to insert a line break after dumping an item in json (I want each item to occupy a single line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're creating is a [JSON lines](http://jsonlines.org) file.

Make the `write` an atomic operation. Call `json.dumps`, get the dumped data as a string, and write it to the file along with the `\n`.

```
j = json.dumps([text, href])
f.write(j + '\n')
```

Comment: What if I'm only appending to file? does the f.write function still work?

Comment: @Fancypants753 Yes, as long as you open the file in `a`ppend mode.

Comment: @Fancypants753 try the other solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure an operation in a thread is atomic, use a lock.  Only one thread at a time can enter the `with lock` section, so you can chain as many operations as you need.

```
import threading
import json

def mythread(lock):
    D = {'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
    for _ in range(100):
        with lock, open("UrlDict.json",'a') as f:
             json.dump(D,f)
             f.write('\n')

lock = threading.Lock()
p1 = threading.Thread(target=mythread,args=(lock,))
p2 = threading.Thread(target=mythread,args=(lock,))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```